# MySQL: Different charsets for different text contents, does it worth?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, utf-8, character-encoding

I have my database with utf8mb4 in all tables and all char/varchar/text columns. All is working fine but I was wondering if I really need it for all columns. I mean, I have columns that will contain user text that require utf8mb4 since the user can type in any language, insert emoticons, and so on. However I have different columns that will contain other kind of strings like user access tokens, country codes, user nicknames that does not contain strange characters, and so on.

Does it worth to change the charset of these columns to something like ascii or latin1? It would improve database space, efficiency? My feel is that set a charset like utf84mb for something that will never contain unicode characters is a waste of 'something'... but I really do not know how this is managed internally by MySQL.

In the other side I am connecting to this database from php and setting the connection charset to uft8mb4, so I suppose that all non utf8 columns will be converted automatically. I suppose is not a problem as utf8 is superset of ascii or latin1.

Any tips? pros and contras? Thanks!

Comment: Utf8 is very small when charset is latin-1, you lose the option of multibyte to gain very little.

Comment: The pros are very little it will only give you more headache as far as coding later so don't do it

Comment: UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, so any text in the range x00-x7F is single byte. It takes the same amount of space in ASCII, Latin-1, or UTF-8. It's not going to be worth changing specific fields (columns) from UTF-8 to ASCII or Latin-1, especially if this is already in production use. As far as processing time goes, you might spend a little more on UTF-8 fields (need to check for multibyte characters), but it shouldn't be a major hit.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to make all your columns and tables defaulting to the same thing, UTF-8.

The long answer is because of the way UTF-8 is encoded, where ASCII will map 1:1 with UTF-8 and not incur any additional storage overhead like you might experience with UTF-16 or UTF-32, it's not a big deal. If you're storing non-ASCII characters it will take more space, but if you're storing those, you'll need the support anyway.

Having mixed character sets in your tables is just asking for trouble. The only exception is when defining `BINARY` or `BLOB` type columns that are not UTF-8 but instead binary.

Even [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) makes it clear the only place this is an issue is with `CHAR` columns rather than `VARCHAR`, but it's not really a good idea to use `CHAR` columns in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is a strict subset of UTF-8, so there is exactly zero gain in space efficiency if you have nothing that uses special characters stored in UTF-8. There is a marginal improvement in space efficiency if you use latin-1 instead of UTF-8 for storing latin-derived text (special characters that UTF-8 uses 2 bytes for can be stored with just one byte in latin-1), but you gain a lot of headaches on the way, and you lose compatibility with wider character sets.

For example, **ñ** is stored as `0xC3 0xB1` in UTF-8, whereas latin-1 stores it as `0xF1`. On the other hand, **a** is `0x61` in both encodings. The clever guys that invented UTF8 did it this way. You save a single byte, only for special characters.

**TL;DR** Use UTF-8 for everything. If you have to ask, you don't need anything else.